# webApi OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider How can i write Logout

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, oauth

Here i wrote sesssion Based Authentication Using **OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider**
This is My code

```
public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
        if (context.UserName == "admin" && context.Password == "admin")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "admin"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "MD"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else if (context.UserName == "user" && context.Password == "user")
        {
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("username", "user"));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, "MD"));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
        else
        {
            context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
            return;
        }
```

Please Help me How can i implement Logout functionality

Comment: which `DefaultAuthenticationTypes` are you using? its a `ExternalBearer` or `ApplicationCookie` or `ExternalCookie`?

Comment: Bearer Authentication

Comment: Have a look on answer here => https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26182660/how-to-logout-user-in-owin-asp-net-mvc5

Comment: @er-shoaib  I had used this code        var ctx = Request.GetOwinContext();
            var authenticationManager = ctx.Authentication;
            authenticationManager.SignOut();
            return Ok();   But its not Deleting Token

Comment: You will get some  [info](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24611815/5514820) here that why your code not deleting token.